# How do you read a GeoJSON file that contains a single feature with the GeoTools gt-geojsondatastore plugin?

Tags: geojson, geotools

I have successfully processed files that contain a `FeatureCollection` using a `GeoJSONDataStore`, but when the file contains a single Feature, all I can manage is to get an empty `FeatureCollection` when I call `getFeatures` from the `FeatureSource` obtained by calling `getFeatureSource` on the `GeoJSONDataStore`.

Comment: can you provide an example file? this sounds like a bug or an invalid file